# How to load data separated by :: in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am having the text file in which fields are separated by :: like below.

```
124::2345::3::647483
234::5940::3::939390
340::3492::3::948284
```

How can i load the data in the pig latin and what is the parameter for using pigStorage??

Answer (score 2):

`PigStorage` only accepts a single character.

Load the data on each line. Use [`STRSPLIT`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.16.0/func.html#strsplit) with a regex pattern to get the fields.

```
A = LOAD 'data.txt' USING PigStorage('\n');
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT($0, '::'));
```

`\d B` Output

```
(124,2345,3,647483)
(234,5940,3,939390)
(340,3492,3,948284)
```